# Selecting and editing rows with select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from table;
```

you can edit and add delete rows

However

```
select field1, field2 from table;
```

You can not edit the returned fileds or add or delete

Is there a way to select specific fields and edit them

Comment: your question is not clear  ..

Comment: You can do a lot of things with SQL, I'd suggest you pick up a tutorial and go through that.

Comment: Don't use `select` just use `update` instead.

Answer (score 3):

To update a particular field, use `UPDATE` query.

```
UPDATE *table*
SET *field1* = 'abc', *field2* = 'xyz'
WHERE *condition*;
```

If you wish to apply the changes to *field1* and *field2* for all rows write
`WHERE 1`;

However, if you want a separate view of a table containing all rows with only *field1* and *field2* as columns, you can create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW *V1* AS
SELECT *field1*, *field2* 
FROM *table*
WHERE *condition*;
```

and make changes to this view as you wish.

Comment: select * from table;

Comment: Select * from Table;

Comment: select * from Table; will return a rows of the table in a grid and you have the option to add, delete, and edit directly to rows in the grid. However, if you create a view or select specific fields in the table you get a grid of rows returned but you can not directly update them. I am using MYSQL Workbench